# Remove a phantom drive letter

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drive-letter

Recently, I plugged a friend's external hard drive on my laptop. Because it didn't show up, I had to manually assign it a drive letter using the disk management in Windows 10.

But now I unplugged it, the drive letters I used still show up in `explorer.exe`. I tried to reboot, checked into the disk management again, even in the registry at `Ordinateur\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`, also with Diskpart using `list volume` or with PowerShell with `Get-Partition`, but they do not appear in any of these situations.

If I try to access them using command-line (`S:` or `R:`), I get a message telling the specified path was not found, while if I try a non-existent drive (like `Y:`) I simply get a message telling the *drive* is not found.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? I gone through a lot of forums but didn't find anything...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "the drive letters I used still show up. " Where was this?

Comment: In the files explorer (`explorer.exe`)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate post of https://superuser.com/questions/996189/how-to-remove-phantom-drive-letters/996207