# Drive letters are not available in "Change Drive Letter and Paths"

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, drive-letter

My semi-permanent USB drive died, so I copied all the files to a replacement.  Now I would like to assign the new drive the same drive letter as the old, so I don't have to change the path in every program and shortcut that points to it.  Unfortunately, the drive letter (F) is not available in the list of options:

[image]

The other drives on the system are C D G (and E is for the DVD-ROM), so it's not missing because it's in use.  I've rebooted multiple times, and completely uninstalled the non-existent drive using [USBDeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html), but its drive letter is still unavailable.

Comment: F is missing because it is assigned to anther drive,

Comment: @Moab The drive it was assigned to no longer exists

Comment: I believe Windows thinks it exists.  I see this here with internal drives

Comment: @John - "I believe Windows thinks it exists." - So how does the author resolve their problem? If the drive is no longer installed in the system the drive letter should be available.

Comment: I just had to use a new Letter. The old one could not be used

Comment: There must be a way to re-enable it from the registry or something

Comment: OHHHHH.  It *is* assigned to a (virtual) drive.  I opened File Explorer and entered `F:` in the location bar, and it shows a Google Drive.  I can change that drive letter from Google Drive's settings, and then the letter becomes available

Comment: Does that drive letter show in explorer?

Comment: @Moab Yes, but I think only after I rebooted and Google Drive grabbed it, and I didn't look after that point, I had only looked before rebooting

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/996189/how-to-remove-phantom-drive-letters

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Open CMD command prompt as administrator > type "mountvol /r" without quotes, then press [enter]. Reboot and try again.

The command mountvol /r will remove drive letters for previously connected drives.

Answer (score 0):

The drive letter may be assigned to a different drive, even if it's not shown in **Disk Management** or `diskpart`.  Try just entering the drive letter into a File Explorer to verify this.

In my case, the problem was caused by Google Drive being assigned to drive G, which was already in use, so after I removed the old USB stick and rebooted, Google Drive gobbled up the next available letter F for its virtual drive.  It allows this to be changed in the settings, though:

[image: Google Drive change Drive letter]

which then made the letter available in "Change Drive Letter or Path" again.