# There appears to be a "ghost" USB drive on my PC. What should I do?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

Ever since I switched SSDs and installed Windows 10 Pro in the one I'm using right now, I see a "ghost" drive (a not existent drive in gray) that only says "Insert a Disk in USB Device (F:)" when I click on it.

[image: "ghost" drive]

I tried uninstalling it with external devices managers and I can do it without any issue, but after rebooting Windows it appears again. I even tried to uninstall the USB Drivers from the Device Manager, but nothing changed. I noted that this **only** happens if I restart my PC with the **"Restart"** option. If I turn off and then on the PC the drive doesn't reappear by itself.

If I unmount it using `mountvol F: /D`, the drive will only be invisible (as it reappears but without a drive letter).

After several tests and after using my SD Card reader, I came to the conclusion that the "ghost drive" is just the SD Card reader doing weird things, as if I plug a SD Card it gets replaced by a normal, functional drive containing the content of my SD Card. In fact, if I extract the SD Card using the "Extract" option in Windows, the ghost drive disappears.

Disk Management:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Does it appear in "Disk management"?

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/996189/how-to-remove-phantom-drive-letters) is a potential duplicate

Comment: @Ramhound They are not the same issue, check my comments in DrMoishe Pippik's answer if you want more info.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes it does, but I only have the "Change device letter and access route of device", "Propierties" and "Help" options available.

Comment: @ruben1_PvP - I don't see in the body of your question, where you attempted running `mountvol F: /D` and indicated that after a reboot drive letter was reassigned. You also did not mention this was a card reader, which is vital information to have, since that does make a difference (so much so I solved an identical error recently).

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the disk management page - I didn't ask what options you had for the drive, what would be more useful is what information is shown in disk management page for that drive

Comment: @JaromandaX you can find a screenshot here https://exploiter.info/uidy0nru.png

Comment: @Ramhound 
1. That's why I said that you could read my comments if you needed more info.
2. I applied that command and no, the letter was not reassigned. It doesn't show in "My PC" anymore (because it doesn't have a letter) but it does in Disk Management.
3. I didn't know it was vital info
4. What recent identical error are you referring to? The one you posted has marked as answer the OP saying it got solved after a Windows Update, something that it's obviously out of my hand knowing I have my PC updated.

Comment: We shouldn't have to read comments, useful info should be added to OP.

Comment: If this reappears after startup it means either that a) there's something configured in BIOS or b) there is actual hardware that Windows detects. Sometimes this can be an SD card reader which might be optional in your PC configuration, which is registered on the chipset but not physically present.

Comment: @1NN I indeed have a USB Floppy: Generic STORAGE DEVICE device (I thought it was the ghost drive as the name of its controller is "Generic Storage Device") in my boot list in BIOS, but after disabling it and booting into windows the ghost drive still appears.
However, you just made me remember that I forgot to say that I know that that "ghost drive" is linked to my (physical) SD Card reader, as if I insert one in the slot the ghost drive gets replaced by a real drive referring to the SD Card I inserted. I'll add it to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

First, look for a device inadvertently left plugged into a USB port, such as µSD card reader.

If there is nothing plugged in, then test [removing it from the *list* of USB devices](https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-Record-of-USB-Plug-in-Equipment) that have *ever* been connected, which is kept in the Registry.

The free utility from Nirsoft, [USBDevView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html), makes that simple:

[image: USBDevView]

- Right-click a device.
- Select whether to *Disable* (immediately reversible) it or *Uninstall* it.

There is no problem if a device is removed; Windows will jsut take a few seconds the next time that device is used to analyze it and add it back to the list.

Comment: When I said " I tried uninstalling it with external devices managers" I meant with tools like USBDevView and similar. That is great and solves the problem but only until I restart my PC.

Comment: Does it show as connected? Then look for a device plugged in -- start by unplugging *all* USB devices, remove as before with USBDevView, and then plug each in again one at a time, checking if the haunting has manifested again. Also, could it be a built-in card reader?

Comment: I did as you told me and the same happens: the ghost device doesn't appear until I reboot my PC. Yes, I do have a card reader. But I always had it, with my old drive too, and I didn't have this problem until now.